# MySQL FIFO policy based on table size

Tags: mysql, size, fifo, sql-timestamp

I have a table in MySQL where arrive continuously data (these data have a timestamp).
I'd like to create a FIFO Queue based on the size of the table.
I mean, if I set for example 1GB as threshold and the data begin to be stored once I reach 1 GB of capacity I start to delete data in a fifo way.
Anyone have any suggestions or have ever done anything similar?

Thank you

Comment: I don't think there's anything that will automatically delete the older records. You can use Event Scheduler to periodically delete old records.

Comment: A common strategy is to use partitions based on date. When you add a new partition for the next date, you remove the oldest partition.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused on the definition of a FIFO queue. You don't describe any consumer of the queue, only deletions.

It sounds more like a least-recently-used cache, that holds up to 1GB of data, but the "oldest" data is overwritten as new data is inserted.

MySQL is neither a cache nor a queue. MySQL is a database. It is designed to store all the data you insert into it, durably. It has no feature to do automatic deletion.

I suggest you should use a cache server such as redis. It has the feature you are looking for, to evict data if the collection exceeds a fixed size.

See the post: [Using Redis as an LRU cache](https://redis.io/topics/lru-cache)